# How delete column delimeter in cocoa application?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, cocoa, interface-builder

I`m newbie in Mac OS X programming. Im trying to set columns number to one, but column delimeter in my interface is still there. How can i delete it ?
[image: Setting columns in Interface Builder]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An IB Bug (I think) that has existed for a very long time.  Just resize the Table View so that it's smaller than the delimeter and then change it back to the original size you want.